# Remove data from a mongo document with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the next array obtained from Mongo:

```
array(10) {
  ["_id"]=>
  object(MongoId)#25 (1) {
    ["$id"]=>
    string(24) "4ea062b9271e012227000000"
  }
  ["email"]=>
  string(18) "your@email.tld"
  ["group"]=>
  int(1)
  ["last_login"]=>
  int(1319299712)
  ["login_hash"]=>
  string(40) "a67b25998576d454c7a422908592ed338561a527"
  ["password"]=>
  string(44) "EK341WsJRo1vUB9vGYWfogfzstZsIg77/oRqlpeQH+I="
  ["profile_fields"]=>
  string(6) "a:0:{}"
  ["username"]=>
  string(7) "loremipsum"
  [0]=>
  string(10) "login_hash"
  [1]=>
  string(40) "9de77184cb57625f834879b3cbcdf0b860d842c1"
}
```

Doing tests I have added bad information to that document, the last 2 keys of the array: 0 and 1. My question is how I can delete that info or another label with Mongo and using PHP?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do not know how to handle it in php, but you can use a modifier to delete a single field: $unset. See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating

Answer (score 0):

In this case the exact command you need is:

```
db.collection.update(
    {"_id": ObjectID("4ea062b9271e012227000000")},
    {"$unset": [0: true, 1: true]}
);
```

In php this would be like:

```
$mongoClient = new MongoClient();
$db = $mongoClient->selectDB('your_DB_name');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'your_collection_name');
$collection->update(
    ['_id' => new MongoId("4ea062b9271e012227000000")],
    ['$unset' => [
        0 => true,
        1 => true
    ]]
);
```