# How to delete fields from Mongodb (Mongo PHP)?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongoose

I tried to delete field from document in Mongo terminal like as:

```
db.getCollection('objects').update({}, {$unset: {'value.speed':''}} , {multi: true});
```

It works, but how to write this in Mongo PHP(old version).

I tried:

```
$find = [
    'value' => ['$exists' => true]
];

$update = [];

$update['$unset']['value']['speed'] = null;

$this->collection->update($find, $update, ['multiple' => true]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$update` usage is incorrect. Try something like the following:

```
$update = [
    '$unset' => [        
        'value.speed' => true
    ]
];
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261521/mongodb-update-nested-array) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860792/remove-data-from-a-mongo-document-with-php) post, or search for similar to understand better.

Comment: Can I use dynamically array as: `$update = [
            '$unset' => [
                'value.'.$data["prefix"] => true
            ]
        ];`?

Comment: @Yahorow, yes, this is a regular string value after all